# How do I traversing a hidden div in Prototype like in jquery?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

The jquery way is

```
$("#id:hidden:first")

$("#id:visible:last")
```

What's the Protoytype ways?

I try using `$$()`, and it doesn't work.

could somebody tell me? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$$('#id[style="display:none"]:first')
```

this should be faster:

```
$$('#id[style="display:none"]').first()
```

See

- http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar
- http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
$$('#id[display=none]:first');
```

Comment: but I have a additional question, because I try 

$$('#id[style="display:block"]').first()

seems doesn't work.

what I thouth is 
$$('.class').each(function(i){
  //get first element style != block here.
})

but I think this way is not simple enough.

do you have any idea?